# How to set DataGrid cell content depending on binding value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I set a `DataGrid`'s cell value depending on the binding content?

Example:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myBooleanValue}">
```

If the value of `myBooleanValue` is true, I would like to set the content to a button, otherwise the content should be empty.

Comment: Did you consider changing it to a template column and using a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the property `CellTemplateSelector`

A good explanation is here:

[Apply conditional data template in DataGrid](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/apply-conditional-data-template-in-data-grid/)